# Sharepoint 2010 different masterpage for normal user and admin user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do you make Sharepoint 2010 use a custom master page for a set of users and use another custom master page for another set of users?

Basically I am trying to show a branded cutdown version of Sharepoint to one set of user and present the full admin interface to the admins.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible. There is one Master Page associated with a SPWeb ([`SPWeb.MasterUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.masterurl.aspx)).

Your only possibility to have different "master pages" for different types of user is to use security trimming. You will have to use WebParts and other security trimmed stuff to show different content for admins/normal users.

Comment: Thank you. How do most users simplify the ribbon interface for different share point skill level users? Or it's the same interface for everyone? What if I really want to hide some buttons for one set of users?

Comment: You can hide buttons by just setting differnt permissions, i.e. if a user doesn't have the edit permission he will not be able to see the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

there is a solution for this. Usually we create two different master pages to manage this. One master page for administrators containing all staff that is usable for administratos like Ribbon for example.

Other version is only fp anonymous users where HTML generated is clean and no extra SharePoint staff generated for end user. This reduces traffic and time load of page for anonymous users.

[This](http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/using-a-different-master-page-for-authenticated-users-in-sharepoint/) is very useful article how it can be done. We have implemented in the same way and work well.

hope it helps you,

Andrew

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have different ribbons for different logged in user groups?

Comment: Hi. What exactly do you mean? Different buttons accordingly to user's rights or different styles?